# Hybris flexible search query that will return data in certain format, outputting customers and their replies + comments

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Write a flexible search query that will return data in the next format: first column - customer first and last name concated with space, second column - amount of all replies to the left comments.

1) Which table is the one that contains customer comments and replies? I can't seem to find it.

2) How do I achieve the asked format?

Comment: You need to mix DB syntax with flexible search. Mix I mean because you need aggregate functions for the "amount". Also you don't need to know the table names, you only need to know which type to look for (Product, Customer, etc) as flexible search translates it to the correct table on the DB.

Comment: What do you mean with "customer comments" and "replies"? do you mean "reviews"? Or are those part of your project code?

Comment: @Sukram yeah, reviews

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a question that is answerable?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions so you will be better prepared and able to ask a question that will be well received and more importantly **answerable**. This is not a *send me teh codez* site, that is now how this site works.

Answer (score -1):

The `Customer` already saves the first and last name space-separated in the field `name`, so that part is easy.

The getting the reviews in the mix is easily done via `JOIN`, and counting per customer is just a matter of `COUNT(...)` in combination with `GROUP BY`

The final query looks like this:

```sql
select {c:name}, count({r:pk}) as '# Reviews'
from {CustomerReview as r join Customer as c on {r:user} = {c:pk}}
group by {c:pk}
```

Remember: Flexible Search is basically SQL with some hybris-specific magic sprinkled on top.

Comment: thanks. yeah, it's very similar to SQL. however, when I try to select something from CustomerReview, I get an error: Exception message: type code 'CustomerReview' invalid

Comment: I've tested the above query on  a vanilla accelerator (installer script `b2c_acc`). Looks like you don't use the out-of-the-box types in your project. But the concept of the query stays the same